# Calling remote server from a site

Tags: php

I am building a survey site and want to give users the ability to embed my code on their website. When they are done with the settings, two codes are given to them. One to display the survey and the other to embed on the confirmation page to send me back data. I tried using an iframe to deliver the survey on their site but it did not pass data to the confirmation page. 
  I guess its a parent-iframe problem. I also want to know how i can use javascript to deliver the survey instead of iframe and how the javascript would connect with php.

Comment: Did you try making the included page a one pager, meaning one file displays survey and process it.

Comment: I am not sure what that confirmation page is for. I think there should only be one piece of codes for the user to embed on his site.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using GET method (if possible) to pass data from an iframe of a different domain to yours. Browsers, normally, block POST (I assume you have tried that) requests that are cross-domain, using iFrames.

Another approach would be learning about Cross-site/domain XMLHttpRequests or Cross-Domain AJAX, whatever they call it. The only thing is that users would need to have Javascript enabled for that to work, but I dont think you care at all in this case.